# why mapStateToProps back undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i create action and reducer and tested with fake API site in console.log i have list of my post but i can not use them in mapStateToProps.
when i write console.log(state) in mapStateToProps state will show theright data but when i write consloe.log(state.books.data) back undefined .

tanx for helping me

this is my code

```js
//actions
import axios from 'axios';
const ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
export const FETCH_BOOKS = 'FETCH_BOOKS';
export const fetchBooks = () => {
  const request = axios.get(ROOT_URL);
  return {
    type: FETCH_BOOKS,
    payload: request
  }
};

//reducer
import {FETCH_BOOKS} from '../actions/actions_books';
const bookInitialState = [];
export const booksReducers = (state = bookInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BOOKS:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {booksReducers} from './reducer_books';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: booksReducers
});
export default rootReducer;

//component/BookList.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchBooks} from '../actions/actions_books';
import _ from 'lodash'
class BooksList extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.fetchBooks();
  };
  renderBooks = () => {
    _.map(this.props.books, (book) => {
        return <li className="list-group-item">{book.id}</li>
      }
    )
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.renderBooks()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state', state.books);
  return {books: state.books}
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchBooks})(BooksList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, a network request is done in the `fetchBooks` action creator.

[Network requests should be inlined in `componentDidMount`](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/302) lifecycle method in part to move such logic from action creator (remember SRP) and resolve the network request before dispatching the action. *e.g.*

```
class BooksList extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get(ROOT_URL)
     .then(response => this.props.fetchBooksSuccess(response.data))
     .catch(err => this.props.fetchBooksError(err));
  };
...
}
```

...

```
export const fetchBooksSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
    payload: data
  }
};
```

Usually the case when using `redux-saga` is to dispatch an action to `FETCH_BOOKS` and have the network request effected in defined sagas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty straight forwards, you are firing an `async` request in `componentDidMount` function which is executed after render cycle. However even if you have the request in `componentWillMount`, since the request is async before you get the result your render cycle will be called and so will `mapStateToProps` and hence `state.books.data` will give you `undefined`. When the async request is successful and you have the data, you can access `state.books.data`

Comment: i change it to componentWillMount but state.book.data back undefined

Comment: As I said, your network request are async, so it doesn't matter if you add it in componentwillMount or componentDidMount, you probably need to add a check for undefined when trying to loop over your data

Comment: i use redux-promise as middleware and my problem is fixed. but i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of promise `.then()` of `axios` as mentioned by @Shubham Khatri.

API calls will always be asynchronous and your javascript(reactjs) will NOT wait for the response. That is why you get `undefined` value.

Using Promise to resolve the API call is the solution, I feel.